# How I can make a linear gradient legend using Leaflet

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet, legend

i asked this question on gis.stackexchange by they said i should ask here
I'm working on project that visualize solar energy data using Leaflet, I want to add a map legend when i add a lot of values the legend box get bigger and out of the map
 this is my try image  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqSv6.png) and code.

this the wanted legend result [exp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6JSx.png)

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([31.7945, -7.0849], 5,
 );

 L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
   '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
   'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  id: 'mapbox/light-v9'
 }).addTo(map);
  
  var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

 legend.onAdd = function(map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create("div", "legend");
    div.innerHTML += "<h4>Legend</h4>";
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(105,  0,  0,255)"></i><span> 2750</span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(110,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(115,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(120,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(125,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(130,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(135,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(140,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(145,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(150,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(155,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(160,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(165,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(170,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(175,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(180,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(185,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(190,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(195,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(200,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(205,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(210,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(215,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(220,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(225,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(230,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(235,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(240,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(245,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(250,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  0,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  3,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  3,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  3,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  3,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  3,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  3,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  3,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  3,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  3,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  3,  0,255)"></i><span></span><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<small>GHI (kWh/an/m²)<small>';
  return div;
  };

  legend.addTo(map);
```

```css
 #map { width: 1080px; height: 720px; }
  .legend {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  font: 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);*/
  line-height: 18px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.legend h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.legend span {
  bottom: 3px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.legend i {
    width: 20px;
    height: 5px;
    float: left;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<head>

 <title>t</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the span elements and add a `line-height:5px;` to `.legend` element.

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([31.7945, -7.0849], 5,
 );

 L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
   '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
   'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  id: 'mapbox/light-v9'
 }).addTo(map);
  
  var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

 legend.onAdd = function(map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create("div", "legend");
    div.innerHTML += "<h4>Legend</h4>";
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(105,  0,  0,255)"></i>2750<br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(110,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(115,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(120,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(125,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(130,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(135,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(140,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(145,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(150,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(155,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(160,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(165,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(170,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(175,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(180,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(185,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(190,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(195,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(200,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(205,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(210,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(215,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(220,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(225,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(230,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(235,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(240,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(245,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(250,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  0,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  3,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  3,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  3,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  3,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  3,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  3,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  3,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  3,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  3,  0,255)"></i><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<i style="background: rgba(255,  3,  0,255)"></i><br><br>';
    div.innerHTML += '<small>GHI (kWh/an/m²)<small>';
  return div;
  };

  legend.addTo(map);
```

```css
 #map { width: 1080px; height: 720px; }
  .legend {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  font: 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 5px;
}
.legend h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.legend span {
  bottom: 3px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.legend i {
    width: 20px;
    height: 5px;
    float: left;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<head>

 <title>t</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>

</body>
</html>
```